# TSQL - multiple Count from DOB in single query

Tags: t-sql

Sorry if this is a newbie question.  Is it possible to get a list of Count using different where conditions in a single query.
Basically I am trying to get a list showing the number of applicants by age.
example
20 - 29
30 - 39
etc

Thanks so much,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH AgeGroups AS (
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, DOB, GETDATE()) / 365.25 BETWEEN 20 AND 29 
      THEN '20 - 29'
    WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, DOB, GETDATE()) / 365.25 BETWEEN 30 AND 39 
      THEN '30 - 39'
  END AS AgeGroup
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
  AgeGroup,
  COUNT(*) AS AgeGroupCount
FROM AgeGroups
GROUP BY AgeGroup
```

Comment: AWESOME!  Thanks for the very quick response,
Andy

Comment: @andycicchillo Hope it helps... if this answer, or another answer, solved your issue, [please mark it as the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work for you

```
SELECT SUM(case where DATEDIFF(YEAR, [dob], GETDATE()) between 20 and 29 then 1 else 0) AS 'Age_20_29',
SUM(case where DATEDIFF(YEAR, [dob], GETDATE()) between 30 and 39 then 1 else 0) AS 'Age_30_39',
[etc.]
FROM myTbl
```